# Dynamic Slideshow from Foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm currently working on a digital signage project for my work and most of the back end stuff is done.  However, a crucial issue that I've run into is how to display my output from my query into a slideshow format.  Currently all the output is just dumped on the site as an array of images.  I've been trying to find out how to utilize jquery with this issue but I'm not very strong in that area and not sure how to implement it correctly.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

I have some query code that I'm omitting but as far as where I'm stuck, this is all I have for output...

```
<?php

$show = array();

foreach ($rows as $k=>$v) {
    $show[] = '<img src="https://cdn.centralgatech.edu/digitalSignageImages/thumbs.php?file='.$v['content_name'].'" class="img-responsive" width="100%" alt="'.$v['content_desc'].'" height="100%">';
}

print_r($show);

?>
```

Comment: Sorry about that.  It should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you have to make `$.get()` ajax call and then insert html retrived from backend in your DOM using `append` jQuery method.

Let's say your backend returns something like `<h1>Hello world</h1>` on calling `http://your-domain.com/get-h1`

Now you just have to call it from javascript like

```
$.get(http://your-domain.com/get-h1, function(response) {
     $('.your-element').append(response);
});
```

and your greating will appear on page.

Comment: Would you mind showing an example of this?  I'm pretty new to jQuery and Ajax.

Comment: do not forget about `<div class="your-element"></div>` it is a plase where your data will be inserted